# How to dynamically call function with a for loop within Chart.js (JS)

Tags: javascript, for-loop, chart.js

I have a problem:
I'm using chart.js, and I'm trying to iterate with a **for loop** and to call a different function on each loop.

here's what I mean:

That's my function:

```
    const courbeSatisfactionserv = document.getElementById("courbe-satisfaction-service-chart");


    if (courbeSatisfactionserv) {
      const courbe_satisfaction_serv = new Chart(courbeSatisfactionserv, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: createLabelsCourbe(date),
            datasets: function() {
              for (let i = 0; i < (courbeSatisfactionserv.dataset.size); i++) {
                return {
                  datalabels: {
                    display: false,
                  },
                  label: JSON.parse(courbeSatisfactionserv.dataset.?),
                  data: JSON.parse(courbeSatisfactionserv.dataset.?),
                  fill: false,
                  borderColor: '#442B48',
                  backgroundColor: '#442B48',
                  borderWidth: 2
                }
              }
            }
          },
        options: {
          scales: {
            xAxes: [{
               gridLines: {
                  display: false
               }
            }],
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    suggestedMin: 0,
                    suggestedMax: 10
                },
                gridLines: {
                drawBorder: false,
                display: false
                }
            }]
          }
        }
      });
    }
```

What I want to do is for the `data`and the `label` to basically call this:

```
label: JSON.parse(courbeSatisfactionserv.dataset.points_lab_0),
data: JSON.parse(courbeSatisfactionserv.dataset.points_0),
```

for the first iteration, `points_lab_1` and `points_1` for the second iteration and so on...

**I tried this:**

```
label: JSON.parse(courbeSatisfactionserv.dataset.this["points_lab_"+i]),
data: JSON.parse(courbeSatisfactionserv.dataset.this["points_"+i]),
```

but it doesn't work

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That for-loop never gets beyond the first iteration because the body contains a `return`.  To return an array resulting from all iterations, create an array variable, push to it in the loop, then return that array...

```
        datasets: function() {
          let labelObjects = [];
          let dataset = courbeSatisfactionserv.dataset; // easier on the eyes
          for (let i = 0; i < (dataset.size); i++) {
            let labelObject = {
              datalabels: {
                display: false,
              },
              label: JSON.parse(dataset[`points_lab_${i}`]),
              data: JSON.parse(dataset[`points_${i}`]),
              fill: false,
              borderColor: '#442B48',
              backgroundColor: '#442B48',
              borderWidth: 2
            }
            labelObjects.push(labelObject);
          }
          return labelObjects;
        }
```

Comment: @Xander - sorry, I should have done a more thorough job understanding your code (actually, your data structure as implied by the code).  See edit.  There were two problems: (1) the early return, as I noted, (2) the formation of a key into dataset, based on the index of the loop.

Comment: worked like a charm, thank you very much (actually it didn't worked with the function **inside** the chart creation but I created it outside and it worked). Thanks for your time !